# pymacs-report-error: Python: TypeError: pymacs_load_helper() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, emacs, rope, pymacs

Spent quite some time trying to install and configure Pymacs + ropemacs and friends onto my Mac OS 10.9 / Emacs 24.3 system and I am seeing the following issue when attempting to load any module (including ropemacs):

```
pymacs-report-error: Python: TypeError: pymacs_load_helper() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

My environment:

```
rope==0.9.4
ropemacs==0.7
ropemode==0.2
pymacs==tip
```

My init.el:

```
(require 'pymacs)
(autoload 'pymacs-apply "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-call "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-eval "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-exec "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-load "pymacs" nil t)
(pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")
(setq ropemacs-enable-autoimport t)
```

I'd really appreciate any help or information you can provide me so that I can use ropemacs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Interestingly enough, I have found a way to finally get it to work, mostly helped by [this](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/05/my-emacs-python-environment/) and [this](http://blog.csdn.net/ispcfs/article/details/7518151) post. The one thing that made the difference was running emacs -batch -eval '(byte-compile-file "~/.emacs.d/vendor/pymacs-0.25/pymacs.el")'

Comment: Wrote about it here: http://ogmaciel.tumblr.com/post/69506709181/emacs-rope-for-python-development

Comment: There's a bug report filed for this in the official repository. Nobody's bothered to merge it yet, though: https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs/pull/51

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I just may fork the project and include that patch :)